# Lucene: Create document from already preprocessed data

Tags: java, lucene

In our infrastructure, we have existing mechanisms for document modeling which I want to integrate with Lucene. Currently, I'm facing the problem, that I have an already existing document vector and I need to create a Lucene document from it (using Lucene's analyzers is not an option). For simplicity, let's assume, that I have a map containing the terms and their frequencies, I'm currently doing something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> termCounts = getTermCounts(text);
for (String term : termCounts.keySet()) {
   for (int i = 0; i < termCounts.get(term); i++) {
      document.add(new Field("text", term, FIELD_TYPE));
   }
}
```

Doesn't look like an optimal solution to me. Is there a better way, to create a Lucene document from an existing `Map`, `Collection`, `Iterable`?

Comment: Why is this bothering you ? I think this is the way solr handles multi valued fields

Comment: Having to add multiple Field instances for the same term value to the document, did not feel very efficient to me, that's why I wanted to find out, if there's a better way.